# Angular: which is better -- use chained observable subscribes or wrap with a property?

Tags: angular, angular2-observables

Learning to use Angular 4, I'm wondering whether components binding a Property, that in turn invokes a service is more 'expensive' than chaining the subscriptions to an observable. Consider the following:

The POC I'm working with has a MenuComponent, which is relying on a local MenuService, which is in turn using a common NavigationService, which is in turn using http to fetch navigation information as json.

```
/Navigation/MenuComponent
           /MenuService
/Services/NavigationService
```

The `MenuComponent` has a `NavigationDetails[]` public `Property` that in turn wraps a  `NavigationDetails[]` public `Property` within the local `MenuService`, which in turn is wrapping a `NavigationDetails[]` public `Field` within the NavigationService, that was filled when the subscription to the http response triggered.

Somehow it gets triggered (is it working via polling?) and the UI Component refreshes. Neat.

But `NavigationService` could have instead created a public `Observable<NavigationDetails[]>` property, that the `MenuService` could have subscribed to, which in turn the `MenuComponent` could have subscribed to... it's less abstracted than the first option in that `MenuService` has to not only include references to `Observables`, etc. but also `subscribe()`, etc, making the code more brittle to maintain. But if the first option is computationally intense (eg: via Polling) then maybe it's necessary?

Is there a generally accepted/recommended way to keep components blithfully unaware of common global services and just rely local services properties?

Thanks!

Comment: Angular does not employ polling. It relies on Zone.js, which at a high level, monkey patches browser events and API calls so that it knows when to trigger a refresh.

Comment: Good to know. 
So are we saying that there really is no negative to using Properties over subscribing? If so that's great news...

Comment: Right. There are advantages to using both subscribe and input properties though.  For example, if the only reason a component needs to be updated is if the input property reference changes (called an immutable property), then you can change the ChangeDetectorStrategy by skipping whole sub-trees. FYI, the default ChangeDetectorStrategy is to check all all @Input properties, of every component.